# service "redis" refers to undefined volume abcdrf: invalid compose project

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

This is just an example docker-compose file, where I am trying to create a container out of it. The problem I am getting while building a container is the below error

*"service "redis" refers to undefined volume abcdrf/: invalid compose project"*

Please can anyone help me what is wrong happening in this case.

Below is my example docker-compose file code...

```
version: '2'
services:
 redis:
  image: redis:2
  volumes:
    - abcdrf/:/.
  command: "redis-server --notify-keyspace-events Ex"
volumes:
  abcdrf:
```

Comment: there shouldn't be a / at the end of `abcdrf` and I don't support `/` could be a receiver in the container, could you please extend on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to create a sample container using redis image, however it was failing with the error I mentioned for volume above, now that I have removed / after abcdrf, it has started working it. thanks for this... :)